# Can Alphonse sleep in FMA/FMA:B?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In both Fullmetal Alchemist (2003) and Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood (2009), there are instances of Alphonse Elric saying what he can't wait to do once he gets his body back. He usually states things that only humans/living creatures can do that he cannot, such as eating and smelling.

Since sleeping is something that only humans/living creatures (i.e. - not a suit of armor) can do, does this mean that Alphonse cannot sleep? Does he just sit there all night on Ed's floor? Is this talked about/approached differently in the two shows?

Comment: I am about 95% sure that this is addressed in at least one of FMA/FMA:B, and the answer is that Al can't sleep. Hopefully somebody can dig up the relevant details and post an answer.

Comment: Yeah. I also vividly remember that scene. It's been too long so I can't place it any more, but I'm sure there will references to spesific scenes soon enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To simply answer your question. ***No he cannot sleep.*** I found the below referenced in the fma wikia [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alphonse_Elric).

> Additionally, his armor body has several combat advantages including - strengthened offense and defense, imperviability to bullets, inexhaustible stamina, invulnerability against extreme temperatures and an exemption from needing to breathe, eat or ***sleep***.

Although, it only states that there is no need for him to sleep. I am 100% sure that in the anime, Alphonse explains Elric about the horror of not able to sleep and the pain he suffers in solitude. It is a very sad situation that almost makes you want to die.

EDIT:

Found the below content [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alphonse_Elric/History)

> During the night, after Edward's emergency surgery was completed successfully, Alphonse discovered the true tragedy of his new body. ***Incapable of physical sensation and sleep***, he began to feel detached from others and lamented the long solitude of restless night.

This clearly states his disability to sleep.

Answer (score 8):

In chapter 15 of the manga there is a flashback in which Ed says referring to Alphonse:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 20th episode of FMA:Brotherhood, when Alphonce visit Winry, who was irritated by dialog with Ling Yao, she recalls his first night as living armor, when he states, that this body is not able to sleep at all.

Comment: I've added information, where you can see episode I've mentioned. Could we remove this yellow tag below answer?

Answer (score -1):

No, as far as I recall Alphonse doesn't sleep...he sits besides Ed the whole night since he is just an empty suit armour with a blood seal. He doesn't get tired nor does he feel pain of that sort since he doesn't have any senses.